# Get binary value stored in python str

Tags: python, string, binary

```
test_str = 'abc'
```

As we know, the binary value of test_str[0] is 0x61, but how can I get the data in binary mode?

I expect to make `getBinaryData(test_str[0]) == 0x61` True.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#ord), which returns decimal, then use [`bin`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#bin) or [`hex`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#hex) to represent the characters in binary or hex respectively.

```
>>> [bin(ord(i)) for i in test_str]
['0b1100001', '0b1100010', '0b1100011']

>>> [hex(ord(i)) for i in test_str]
['0x61', '0x62', '0x63']
```

Comment: +1 since this is actually what OP wanted ... however I think it hurts because it hampers understanding of representation vs identity, and the fact that python strings are just bytestrings under the hood(at least in 2x)

Answer (score 0):

how bout just

```
test_str = "abc"
test_str[0] == "\x61" == chr(0x61) == unichr(0x61)
```

since python strings are just bytes (at least in python2)

Comment: Actually I just want to convert temp_str[0] into int, is there a simple way?